# How to write test code for template in play framework?

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I want to test my template in `play framework 2.1.*`

**routes** code :

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /signup                     controllers.Application.signup()
```

and **controller** is:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    final static Form<User> usr=form(User.class); 

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(usr));
    }
```

and **view** part is:

```
index.scala.html

@(signupform: Form[User])

@import helper._ 
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._
@main("welcome to EXTR ") {

<div class="container-narrow">
<fieldset>
            <legend>Sign up or <a href="@routes.signin.page" >Sign in</a></legend>

      @helper.form(action=routes.Application.signup()){


      @inputText(
                    signupform("username"),
                    '_label->"Enter Username",
                    '_help  ->  "Please Enter a valid username.",
                    '_error -> signupform.globalError)

      @inputText(
                    signupform("name"),
                    '_label->"Enter name",
                    '_error -> signupform.globalError)

      @inputPassword(
                    signupform("password"),
                    '_label->"Enter Password",
                    '_help  ->  "Please Enter a valid Password.",
                    '_error -> signupform.globalError)

      @inputPassword(
                    signupform("repassword"),
                    '_label->"Enter Password again",
                    '_error -> signupform.globalError)

      @inputText(
                    signupform("email"),
                    '_label->"Enter email",
                    '_help  ->  "Please Enter a valid Email",
                    '_error -> signupform.globalError)

      <input class="btn  btn-large " type="submit" value="signup" />
      }
      </fieldset></div>

}
```

Now i want to test `index.scala.html` how to write test code for this?

i tried it but not getting

```
@Test
    public void renderTemplate() {
        Content html = views.html.index.render(form(User.class));

       assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
       assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Coco");

    }
```

but when i run not getting any reply for this it is continue running?

so give me some idea to write code for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking for some acceptance tests,

so this is an example of my scala-play project.
You can have an idea from it.

```
  "A Track view" should "render basic data" in running(TestServer(3333)) {

    await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333/track/62584001").get).status must equal (OK)

        await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333/track/62584001").get).body must include ("62584001")
}
```